ERROR Error saving data [TRPCClientError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: B]
I have an App that im creating that takes the user through a onboarding process for their user details.
I have two screens where it is triggered. One on a screen where the user is checking to see if the name they entered is unique:
const handleFormSubmit = async (values:any) => {
    try {
      const isHandleUnique = await mutateAsync({ stageName: values.handle });
      console.log(values);
      console.log("isHandleUnique", isHandleUnique);
      if (isHandleUnique === false)
        return Toast.show("Handle is already taken", {
          duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
          position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM - 100,
          shadow: true,
          animation: true,
          hideOnPress: true,
          delay: 0,
          backgroundColor: "white",
          textColor: "black",
          keyboardAvoiding: true,
          opacity: 1,
        });
      
      // If the stage name is unique, save it to AsyncStorage
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@basicInfoData", JSON.stringify(values));
      navigation.navigate("AddPhoto" as never);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving data", error);
      Toast.show("Error saving data: " + error.message, {
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
        position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM - 100,
        shadow: true,
        animation: true,
        hideOnPress: true,
        delay: 0,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        textColor: "black",
        keyboardAvoiding: true,
        opacity: 1,
      });
    }
  }; 

The other is on the final screen of the onboarding process where it takes all the values that the user entered and pulls them from async data to be passed along to the endpoint call in my trpc user router. This updates user's profile info.
const handleSave = async () => {
    try {
      // Retrieve all necessary values from AsyncStorage
      const storedGenres = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@selectedGenres");
      const storedGoals = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@selectedGoals");
      const storedInstruments = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@selectedInstruments");
      const storedBasicInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@basicInfoData");
      const profileImg = await AsyncStorage.getItem("profileImg");
      const storedPreferredInstrument = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@preferredInstrument");
      const storedLocation = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@location");
      const pushToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("pushToken");
  
      // Parse stored items
      const parsedGenres = storedGenres ? JSON.parse(storedGenres) : [];
      const parsedGoals = storedGoals ? JSON.parse(storedGoals) : [];
      const parsedInstruments = storedInstruments
        ? JSON.parse(storedInstruments).map(({ name, type, proficiency }:any) => ({ name, type, proficiency }))
        : [];
      const basicInfo = storedBasicInfo ? JSON.parse(storedBasicInfo) : { stageName: "", handle: "" };
      const preferredInstrument = storedPreferredInstrument ? JSON.parse(storedPreferredInstrument) : "";
      const location = storedLocation ? JSON.parse(storedLocation) : null;
  
      const formattedAvailability = days.map((day) => {
        if (daysSelected.includes(day)) {
          return {
            day,
            startTime: selectedStartTimes[day as keyof typeof selectedStartTimes],
            endTime: selectedEndTimes[day as keyof typeof selectedEndTimes],
            isSet: true,
          };
        }
        return {
          day,
          startTime: "1:00 AM",
          endTime: "2:00 AM",
          isSet: false,
        };
      });
  
      // Format the profile details to match the endpoint's expected format
      const profileDetails = {
        handle: basicInfo.handle,
        stageName: basicInfo.stageName,
        goals: parsedGoals,
        genres: parsedGenres,
        instruments: parsedInstruments,
        availability: formattedAvailability,
        preferredInstrument,
        location,
        pushToken: pushToken || undefined, // Ensure optional field is correctly handled
      };
  
      // Log profile details for debugging
      console.log("Profile Details being sent:", profileDetails);
  
      // Call the endpoint
      const res = await profileSettings(profileDetails);
      console.log("Profile settings response:", res);
  
      const createStripeCustomer = await mutateAsync();
      console.log("Stripe customer creation response:", createStripeCustomer);
  
      if (res.type === "success") {
        await saveVal("token", res.data.token);
        await saveVal("refreshToken", res.data.refreshToken);
        await saveVal("userId", res.data.userId);
        await AsyncStorage.multiRemove([
          "@selectedGenres",
          "@selectedGoals",
          "@selectedInstruments",
          "@basicInfoData",
          "@preferredInstrument",
          "@location",
          "profileImg",
          "pushToken",
        ]);
  
        dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN",
          payload: {
            userId: res.data.userId,
            stageName: basicInfo.stageName,
            handle: basicInfo.handle,
            profileImg,
            stripeId: createStripeCustomer.data.stripeId,
          },
        });
        navigation.navigate("Invite");
      } else {
        Toast.show("Error saving availability", {
          duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
          position: Toast.positions.CENTER,
          shadow: true,
          animation: true,
          hideOnPress: true,
          delay: 0,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving availability", error);
    }
  };

Both give me the error:
WARN  [TRPCClientError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: B]
ERROR  Error saving data [TRPCClientError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: B]
Here is the trpc endpoint for context:
setProfileDetails: validateRegistrationToken
  .meta({ openapi: { method: "POST", path: "/set-profile" } })
  .input(
    z.object({
      handle: z.string().refine(
        (handle) => {
          if (handle.length > 25) return false;
          if (!/^\w+$/.test(handle)) return false;
          return true;
        },
        { message: "Invalid handle" }
      ),
      stageName: z.string().refine(
        (stageName) => {
          if (stageName.length > 25) return false;
          if (!/^[^\s].*[^\s]$/.test(stageName)) return false;
          return true;
        },
        { message: "Invalid stageName" }
      ),
      bio: z.string().optional(),
      goals: z.array(z.string()),
      genres: z.array(z.string()),
      instruments: z.array(
        z.object({ name: z.string(), type: z.string(), proficiency: z.string() })
      ),
      availability: z.array(
        z.object({
          day: z.string(),
          startTime: z.string(),
          endTime: z.string(),
          isSet: z.boolean(),
        })
      ),
      location: z.string().nullable(),
      preferredInstrument: z.string(),
      pushToken: z.string().optional(),
    })
  )
  .output(outputType)
  .mutation(async (req): Promise<ResponseType> => {
    console.log("Received profile details input:", req.input);
    try {
      // Check if the pushToken already exists
      if (req.input.pushToken) {
        const existingUser = await prisma.users.findUnique({
          where: { pushToken: req.input.pushToken },
        });

        if (existingUser && existingUser.email !== req.ctx.email) {
          // Log an error message for development use
          console.error(`Push token conflict: ${req.input.pushToken} already exists for a different user (${existingUser.email})`);

          // Skip updating the pushToken if it already exists for a different user
          req.input.pushToken = undefined;
        }
      }

      const updatedUser = await prisma.users.update({
        where: {
          email: req.ctx.email,
        },
        data: {
          stageName: req.input.stageName,
          handle: `@${req.input.handle}`,
          goals: req.input.goals,
          genres: req.input.genres,
          instruments: req.input.instruments,
          availability: req.input.availability,
          accountStatus: "COMPLETED",
          location: req.input.location,
          preferredInstrument: req.input.preferredInstrument,
          bio: req.input.bio,
          pushToken: req.input.pushToken ?? null, // Use null if pushToken is not provided or removed
        },
      });

      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          id: req.ctx.userId,
          email: req.ctx.email,
          accountStatus: "COMPLETED",
        },
        envs!.JWTSECRET,
        { expiresIn: "1d" }
      );

      const refreshToken = crypto.randomUUID();

      await redisClient.set(
        refreshToken,
        JSON.stringify({
          id: req.ctx.userId,
          device: "Iphone",
          email: req.ctx.email,
          accountStatus: "COMPLETED",
        }),
        {
          EX: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        }
      );

      const response = { code: 200, type: "success", data: { token, refreshToken, userId: req.ctx.userId } };
      console.log("Sending response:", response);
      return response as ResponseType;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error in setProfileDetails mutation:", err);
      if (!(err instanceof TRPCError)) {
        const errorResponse = new TRPCError({
          code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
          message: "Internal Server Error",
        });
        console.log("Sending error response:", errorResponse);
        throw errorResponse;
      }
      const errorResponse = new TRPCError({ code: err.code, message: err.message });
      console.log("Sending error response:", errorResponse);
      throw errorResponse;
    }
  }),

Ive tried logging the response but cant seem to pin down where this error is happening.

Your code is assuming that all of the values you get from AsyncStorage.getItem are themselves JSON strings.  Is that going to be the case?
